# Shell scripting execution multiple directories

Tags: shell

How can I execute a script in multiple directories simultaneously 
suppose folder X contains directories
A
B
C
D
E

all these directories contains a specific file on which script acts.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

This will apply a script to every file inside every directory inside directory `X`:

```
$ for file in X/*/*; do ./script "$file"; done
```

Comment: this will not execute script on all directories simultaneously.

Comment: A little explanation on why it wouldn't would be nice.

Comment: i wasn't offending you, but 1st: this code will execute for each and every file as well as directory in dir X and its sub directories. 2nd: this will be a serial execution. 3rd: it will require active terminal connection till the end.

Comment: Yes it's true. Since the question wasn't very specific I'd take some liberties. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

use function and run this function in background for each dir in dir X. for e.g.

```
func1()
{
   my dir = $1 # for dirs A,B,C etc
  statements. . . 
}

cd X
while read dir
do
    if [ -d $dir ]
    then
       func1 $dir &
    fi
done <<< "`ls`"
```